# Question about moment with two springs and one weight

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, moment

[image]

The answer to this question is C. I got to it by realizing that if the weight is moved away from the pivot then it will produce an anti-clockwise moment which will cause X to decrease and Y to increase. Thus, moving the weight towards the pivot should do the opposite and accordingly the answer C.

However, I cannot fully understand the concept of this. First of all was the rule in equilibrium before the weight was moved? If it was then were the strings exterting any force? Because their extension is 0 so I think they are not. Secondly, I assumed some values of my own. For example if we say that the weight is 50N then the forces of springs cannot be 25N each because X is also producing moment in anti-clockwise direction. But as they are equally far from the pivot, they should be producing the same force.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The text indicates that the springs are stretched. So,  their extensions are not zero.  The string X acts with an upward force and the string Y acts with a downward force.  The two forces depend on the extension of the respective springs and the springs' elastic constants. They don't have to be equal.  At equilibrium the upward force is larger so the net torque is equal and opposite to the torque of the weight.